# In long polling( PHP/Laravel),is there any possibility for server to Identifying users basing any unique attribute

Tags: php, laravel-4, long-polling

As related to title,I am working on web application using long polling,It had functionality that the server(or)application should indentify all the users connected to it uniquely with some attibute.If any new poll came to server related to user no:123 then the content change or message should only seen by user123 not by others,And if any change or message comes to server regarding user456 only user456 sholud experience the long poll.This the point where i got strucked how does server indentifies particular user and shows exact data related to him.I had successfully working long polling server but got strucked can one help please.Give any idea of implementation or ways

Comment: Offtopic - are you using apache?

Comment: Yes Apache ... XAMPP

Comment: You gonna have a bad time with long polling. You won't notice problems until you spawn dozens of concurrent connections. Server will hang. I had the same problem, ended up with using `Node.js` to work aroung c10k problem. I've also heared that `Nginx` could also do the stuff, but I didn't tested it. More on this issue (and attempt to solve the problem) is in my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080692/long-polling-with-ajax-and-php-apache-freezes